# Wifi Turn on FIRMWARE_LOADER faile error

Tags: android, wifi, firmware, odroid

I am using Odroid A device, which have bcm4239 wifi hardware(according to Hardkernel's spec. i don't know how to check this programatically). i have attached the log when i try to enable the wifi using

mWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true).

I want to know the meaning of the log, especially "E/WifiHW(1175): FIRMWARE_LOADER faile" message.

Thank you!!

Below is the error log!!

> I/WifiHW(1175): /sys/devices/platform/odroid-sysfs/wifi_enable : write success (on = 1)
>
> I/WifiHW(1175): /sys/devices/platform/odroid-sysfs/wifi_nrst : write success (on = 1)
>
> > > > > E/WifiHW(1175): **FIRMWARE_LOADER faile**
>
> D/SoftapController(1079): Softap fwReload - Ok
>
> D/NetworkManagementService(1175): rsp <213 (mac address here) 0.0.0.0 0 [up broadcast running multicast]>
>
> D/CommandListener(1079): Setting iface cfg
>
> D/CommandListener(1079): Trying to bring down wlan0
>
> D/NetworkManagementService(1175): flags <[up broadcast running multicast]>
>
> D/CommandListener(1079): broadcast flag ignored
>
> E/WifiStateMachine(1175): Unable to change interface settings: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to communicate with native daemon to interface setcfg - com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnectorException: Cmd {interface setcfg wlan0 0.0.0.0 0 [down broadcast running multicast]} failed with code 501 : {Flag unsupported}
>
> E/wpa_supplicant(4058): Line 58: WPA-PSK accepted for key management, but no PSK configured.
>
> E/wpa_supplicant(4058): Line 58: failed to parse network block.
>
> I/wpa_supplicant(4058): rfkill: Cannot open RFKILL control device
>
> E/WifiHW(1175): 'GET_NETWORK 0 bssid' fail.
>
> ...

I am using ICS 4.0.4..

Thanks in advance

Comment: i have similar error log when disabling wifi!! Please answer bacause i've spent more than a week without understanding the root cause of this, i digged through SO, no similar questions yet!!

Comment: On a similar Odroid E device, in /dev/vendor/firmware, there're two files, "bcm4329.bin" and  "bcm4326_apsta" which is not in my Odroid A device!! I tried copying those files to the location, but still same error log i get!!